# Meteor update element inside array inside Meteor.user()

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

Meteor newbie here!

Inside Meteor.user() I have inserted a custom property which is an array, defined (in the root Meteor.user() object) like

extra-field : {
var1 : "var1Value",
var2 : "var2Value"
}

I cannot do this from the client, only from the server, for security reasons. However, I don't know how can I set the field "var1" to "my-new-value" and "var2" to "my-new-value-2" using the same query, by keeping all other elements in Meteor.user() object intact.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**$set**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) on the server (and client if [*your rules*](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) allow it)

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: <user_id>},
    {
        $set : {
            var1 : 'var1value',
            var2 : 'var2value',
            'profile.name' : '<new name>' //Change something in a nested object
        }
    }
);
```